# Оповестить члены класса об изменении свойства (не событием)

Tags: c#, ооп

Есть несколько классов. В "главном" классе (class SPO) есть свойство BackupDir - это общий каталог для бэкапов. В SPO есть два члена класса WorkFlash и WorkFtp, в которых в свою очередь есть члены класса LocalFile. Вот в LocalFile формируется конечный каталог хранения бэкапов (backupDir + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar+ DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString). Т.о., если в SPOсвойство BackUpDir изменится, то остальные члены об этом не узнают, так как уже были проинициализированы со старым каталогом. Как LocalFile, да и не только, можно оповещать об этих изменениях?

```
private class LocalFile
{
    private string ArchiveDir;
    public LocalFile(string backupDir)
    {               //C:\backup\25.12.2015
        ArchiveDir = backupDir + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar+ DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString;
    }
}

public class WorkFlash
{
    public WorkFlash()
    {

    }
    LocalFile file = new LocalFile(BackupDir);

}
public class WorkFtp
{

}

public class SPO
{
    string backupDir = @"C:\backup";

    public WorkFlash wFlash = new WorkFlash();
    public WorkFtp wFtp = new WorkFtp();

    public string BackUpDir
    {
        set { backupDir = value; }
        get { return backupDir; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Я бы пошел другим в лоб - сделал бы класс для директории бэкапов, который бы имел (во всяком случае изначально) одно свойство - непосредственно путь. И передавал бы объект этого класса, а в операциях запрашивал бы текущую директорию у этого объекта.

Но, если мне не изменяет память, у C# все было очень мощно со всякими observable-штуками. Правильней было бы идти этим путем, причем WorkFlash / WorkFtp не должны знать про SPO, они должны знать про *источник*, на который подписываться.

Comment: Спасибо, но мне кажется, у DreamChild красивее в итоге выйдет, когда классы допишутся и начну использовать объекты. С вашим подходом мне на каждый чих в методы придётся передавать этот экземпляр класса BackupDir, чтобы получить доступ к его свойству, а в примере DreamChild я меняю свойство BackupDir у основного класса и автоматом получаю "правильные" пути.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ну сделайте в лоб - в сеттере свойства BackUpDir модифицируйте соответствующие свойства для wFlash и wFtp

Answer (score 0):

А какой смысл инициализировать объекты параметром, который в будущем будет меняться? Инициализируйте их ссылкой на родителя (SPO) и пусть они каждый раз получают BackupDir оттуда, где он и лежит. Как-то так:

```
public WorkFlash wFlash = new WorkFlash(this);

LocalFile file = new LocalFile(spo.BackupDir);
```